# The most efficient way to update fields in two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, coldfusion, sql-update

I'm working on a project where I have to update fields in two different tables. First I use .csv file to read values for certain field, then I check values in if statement and then do the update. Before in the old code it was easy because I had only one table and one field to update, now I have two different tables and two fields. To do just an update is easy but I have more than 15 thousand records. I was wondering what is the most efficient way to do this? If I put two separate queries and run update twice that will run almost 30 thousand records. Is there any way to do this at once? If not what would be the best approach to run these updates? Here is my code that I use to run update on ColdFusion server:

```
<cfset updateFile = "C:\MyFiles\Records.csv">

<cffile action="read" file="#updateFile#" variable="recordsFile">
<cfset myarray = ListToArray(recordsFile, chr(13))>
<cfset cnt = ArrayLen(myarray)>

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to=#(cnt)# step="1">
    <cfif len(trim(myarray[i])) GT 0>
        <cfset myrow = #replace(myarray[i],chr(10),'')#>
        <cfset myrow = ListToArray(myrow,",",true)>

        <cfif #myrow[23]# EQ '1'>
            <cfset #myrow[23]# = 'A'>
        </cfif>

        <cfif #myrow[23]# EQ '2'>
            <cfset #myrow[23]# = 'B'>
        </cfif>

        <cfif #myrow[23]# EQ '3'>
            <cfset #myrow[23]# = 'D'>
        </cfif> 

        <cfquery name="UpdateRecords" datasource="test">
            Update Users
            Set FiledCode = '#myrow[23]#'
            Where User_Number = #myrow[1]#
        </cfquery>  

        <cfoutput>#myrow[1]#</cfoutput><br>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Above you can see how my old code looks, now I would have to add one more table and update filed in that table but still read information from the same file(Records.csv) with different position in array. I done updates/insert before but never had huge number of records. Now I have to what for efficiency and find the best way. I f you have any recommendation for this problem please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Minimize the use of ColdFusion for data processing.  Also, use a staging table.  If MySQL has a bulk loader, use it to populate the staging table.  If not, use ColdFusion.  Then update the other tables from the staging table.

Comment: @DanBracuk I never use bulk loader. Can you provide any example for your answer? Thank you.

Comment: I don't use MySQL at all which is why I said, "if MySQL has a bulk loader".  The syntax for writing from one table to another is available on the internet.  It would depend on whether you are doing an insert, delete, or update.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution. As you said the records can go higher (upto 30K) a stored procedure seems to be a better option to go for. You can do it as follows:
First upload the `CSV` file to a location on MySQL server(if the CF and MySQL are on different locations) using `cfftp`.
If MySQL is on same location as CF you can skip the above step.

Create a Stored procedure for updating the desired table with the desired logic inside it.
A rough idea is as follows:
Create a temporary table, say `temp_update_table` with columns required by you. Like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_update_table (meta_key, meta_value)
```

Now insert the csv data to the temporary table using `LOAD DATA INFILE` like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_csv_pathname' 
INTO TABLE temp_update_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' (meta_key, meta_value);
```

And then update the required table like this:

```
UPDATE "table"
INNER JOIN temp_update_table on temp_update_table.meta_key = "table".meta_key
SET "table".meta_value = temp_update_table.meta_value;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp_update_table;
```

After the CSV upload is complete, call the above stored procedure using `cfstoredproc` tag. It will be much more efficient. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495600/import-csv-to-update-rows-in-table)

**Update**
Some benefits of using Stored Procedure include:

- Maintainability: you can change the logic in the procedure without
  needing to edit app1, app2 and app3 calls.
- Security/Access Control:   it's easier to worry about who can call a predefined procedure than it is to control who can access which tables or which table rows.
- Performance (1): if your app is not situated on the same server as your
  DB, and what you're doing involves multiple queries, using a
  procedure reduces the network overhead by involving a single call to
  the database, rather than as many calls as there are queries. In your case using inline query will hit the database server 30K times (for 30K records).
- Performance (2): a procedure's query plan is typically cached,
  allowing you to reuse it again and again without needing to re-prepare it.

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307871/what-are-the-benefits-of-creating-stored-procedures-in-sql-and-mysql)

Comment: basically I will store all records from .csv to temporary table and then do update from that table? Also I did not understand where and what is the purpose of using cfstoreproc ? Can you explain one more time? Thank you.

Comment: All the code from creating temporary table to dropping temporary table along with conditional logic will go inside stored procedure. For what is the purpose of SP read the update.

Answer (score 0):

The most important is making sure you have indexes set up properly on the tables, but there are still efficiency gains to be made after that.

In this case, the biggest gain would probably come from reducing the number of calls to the database, ie: reducing the number of cfquery tags. You could, for example, put the update statements for both tables within that same query tag.

```
<cfquery name="UpdateRecords" datasource="test">
    Update Users
    Set FiledCode = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#myrow[23]#'>
    Where User_Number = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value='#myrow[1]#'>

    Update Table2
    Set something = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#myrow[23]#'>
    Where User_Number = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value='#myrow[1]#'>
</cfquery>
```

If you want to get more complex, you can break that loop into chunks and put it *inside* the `cfquery` tag so that it contains 100 or so update statements.

Another improvement you should make, for both efficiency and security reasons, is to use `cfqueryparam`. This will allow your database engine to cache the query plan, then reuse on the subsequent tens of thousands of call, and protect you from sql injection.

Comment: Second part of your answer should be simple fix for me. But first part what would be the best to put second update in the same query(UpdateRecords) and that way use just one cfquery tag? Or second part where you said to break them into chunks what you mean how that should look like? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Edited to demonstrate multiple updates in one cfquery.