# Is there a cleaner way to insert this data into a SQL row?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

EDIT: 
Question was marked as a duplicate. I am looking to see if there is a cleaner way to insert data into SQL, not how to insert it.

ORIGINAL: 
Just as the title says, can you think of a cleaner way to go about inserting this data into a SQL?

```
cntcn.Open()
Dim nsrtCmnd As String = ("INSERT INTO SQLTable1 (Column1, Column2, Column3,
                        Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8) 
                        VALUES ('" & Data1 & "','" & Data2 & "','" & Data3 & "','" & Data4 & "',
                        '" & Data5 & "','" & Data6 & "','" & Data7 & "','" & Data8 & "');
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()")
Dim qry As New SqlCommand(nsrtCmnd, cntcn)
Dim rslt As Integer = CInt(qry.ExecuteScalar())
sqlID = rslt
cntcn.Close()
```

Comment: Yes you can write a store Proc in sql server then insert using vb.net

Comment: Yes, use *Prepared Statements*!!!

Comment: Its hard to imagine a worse way.

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the useless comment!

Comment: Thanks for the poorly researched question.  [20,226+ posts regarding](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvb.net%5D+or+%5Bc%23%5D+database+insert) db inserts with VB or C#  (not to mention oodles of MSDN examples)

Comment: @DataBox Plutonix isn't wrong, you could easily have found an answer with even the smallest amount of effort on your part.

Comment: The dupe was ones of those listed to the right under **Related**.

Comment: @Plutonix - How is this question considered a duplicate against the answer that was linked? I asked if there was a cleaner way to insert the data into SQL, not how. What I posted already worked and the linked post made no mention of using a Stored Procedure.

Comment: @LarsTech - See the comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
    @Column1 nvarchar(200),
    @Column2 nvarchar(200),
    @Column3 nvarchar(200),
    @Column4 nvarchar(200),
    @Column5 nvarchar(200),
    @Column6 nvarchar(200),
    @Column7 nvarchar(200),
    @Column8 nvarchar(200),
    @outparm int output
AS
    insert SQLTable1 
        (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, 
         Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8)  
        values
        (@Column1, @Column2, @Column3, @Column4, 
         @Column5, @Column6, @Column7, @Column8) 
    select @outparm = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and then call it via:

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", cntcn)
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
command.Parameters.Add("@Column1", Data1);
command.Parameters.Add("@Column2", Data2);
command.Parameters.Add("@Column3", Data3);
command.Parameters.Add("@Column4", Data4);
command.Parameters.Add("@Column5", Data5);
command.Parameters.Add("@Column6", Data6);
command.Parameters.Add("@Column7", Data7);
command.Parameters.Add("@Column8", Data8);
Dim parmout = new SqlParameter("@outparm", SqlDbType.Int);
parmout .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(parmout);

command.ExecuteNonQuery()

result = parmout.Value
```

Comment: You forgot to add the last param to the parameters collection... Overlook perhaps?

Comment: Yes indeed, total miss.  I've updated the answer!

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ChrisSteele - Thank you for the answer. I've managed to get my commands switched over to stored procedures and they work great. However, what makes this method better? The readability or is it less load on the server? Thanks again

Comment: Benefits of stored procedures are discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307871/what-are-the-benefits-of-creating-stored-procedures-in-sql-and-mysql

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks